# An example of $I(X_1\cap X_2)\neq I(X_1)+I(X_2)$ where $X_i$ is an algebraic set.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, zariski-topology

Let $X_i$ be an algebraic set of an affine space $\mathbb{A}^2$ with Zariski topology with $k=\mathbb{C}$. I want to show that $I(X_1\cap X_2)\neq I(X_1)+I(X_2)$ for certain choice of $X_1$ and $X_2$ where $I(X)$ is the ideal of $k[x,y]$ which conists of function that vanish on $X$.

I have this example in mind $X_1=\{(x,y)|x=1\}$ and $X_2=\{(x,y)|x=2\}$. Then we can see that $X_1\cap X_2=\emptyset$, so $I(X_1\cap X_2)=I(\emptyset)=k[x,y]$. From other side,
$$I(X_1)=(x-1)\text{ and }I(X_2)=(x-2)$$
$\Rightarrow$ $I(X_1)+I(X_2)=(x-1)+(x-2)$. Now, I want to show that $k[x,y]\neq(x-1)+(x-2)$. If they are equal, then $y\in (x-1)+(x-2)$, but $y$ does not vanish on $x=1$ and $x=2$ as a polynomial.

How should I interpret this geometrically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example won't work because in fact $(x-1) + (x-2) = k[x,y]$. To see this, note that $1 = x-1 - (x-2) \in (x-1) + (x-2)$.

The real reason this equality doesn't hold is that $I(X)$ is always a radical ideal. So it suffices to choose $X_1$ and $X_2$ such that $I(X_1) + I(X_2)$ is not radical. This would mean that $\frac{k[x,y]}{I(X_1) + I(X_2)}$ contains nilpotents, which makes me think of tangent vectors. So let's try two curves that are tangent at a point, say $X_1: y = 0$ and $X_2: y = x^2$. Can you show that $I(X_1) + I(X_2)$ is not radical?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It does make sense. I will try to show that $I(X_1)+I(X_2)$ is not radical.

Comment: So, $I(X_1)+I(X_2)$ is not radical for the following reason. First, observe that $I(X_1)=(y)$ and $I(X_2)=(y-x^2)$, so $I(X_1)+I(X_2)=(y)+(y-x^2)=(y,x^2)$. We need to show that $\sqrt{(y,x^2)}=(y,x)$ and use the fact that $(y,x)\neq(y,x^2)$ (one of this ideal is maximal and another is not). For $\sqrt{(y,x^2)}=(y,x)$, we can see that the inclusion $(y,x)\subseteq\sqrt{(y,x^2)}$ is obvious as if $f\in (y,x)$ then $f^2\in(y,x^2)$, and another inclusion $\sqrt{(y,x^2)}\subset(y,x)$ follows from the fact that $f^n\in(y,x^2)\subset (y,x)$ and $(y,x)$ is maximal i.e. prime ideal, so $f\in(y,x)$.

Comment: @user89898989 That looks right to me. The key is really that $x^2 \in (x^2, y)$, but $x \notin (x^2,y)$. This becomes even more apparent when we take the quotient since $\frac{k[x,y]}{(x^2,y)} \cong \frac{k[x]}{(x^2)}$, so $x$ is a nilpotent in the quotient.